# SQL Server - Is there any way or any global event where I can write Insert SQL?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to track each and every execution event of all the stored procedures of a database, So Is there any way or any global event where I can write SQL to insert record into a table along with stored procedure name or object id?

There are so many stored procedures in my database and I can't make changes to all the SP's and re-deploy them. I need global event where I can write the SQL.

I know we have sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats view (Show's last execute date time from cache), but I want to track manually by insert record for each SP into a separate table.

Answers will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For that purpose you can create separate table and write a trigger for insert, update and delete for each table in your database so you can manually track the all type of transaction. Or write only insert trigger for each and every table which tables are used in your stored procedure.

Comment: This is not really a global event as the OP wanted but I do also believe this will be the only way to do it.

Comment: How does this track the *execution* of every *stored procedure*?